# Mostrar aspas vindas do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Em MySQL tenho uma tabela com o seguinte dado:

```
“Cavalo dado não se olha os dentes”, disse a professora
<br>
Segunda linha
```

Estou pegando esse campo assim:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT texto FROM noticia');
$sql->execute();
$resultadoSql = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach($resultadoSql as $valorSql){
    $texto = nl2br($valorSql['texto']);
}
```

Mas está me retornando isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque entra esses quadrados? Como mostrar as aspas?

Comment: Caro Caio, esta com cara de que isso não são aspas, pelo menos não aspas do ASCII, pode ser um UNICODE, pode ser erro de codificação da página, pode ter sido problema no INSERT (creio que o mais provavel);

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado pela ajuda. Esses dados vieram de um banco de dados em Wordpress, estou acessando a tabela post do Wordpress. Realmente se eu edito o conteúdo e recoloco as apas, aparece. O que pode ser? E como resolver?

Comment: Me parece provavel ser alguma conversão das aspas ASCII em algum unicode, talvez o proprio WP esteja convertendo na hora de salvar, tornando em `“` (`U+201C`) quando a aspas `"` forem a esquerda e `”` (`U+201D`)... Note que apesar de semelhantes aos da tabela ASCII não se tratam do mesmo codepoint. Sua página PHP deve estar em iso-8859-1 ou windows-1252 (ambos assumidos pelo apache ou pelo navegador), ou se seu PHP estiver mesmo em UTF-8 então significa que esses caracteres não são aspas tradicionais, mas sim aspas criadas pela propria turma do WP para usar codepoints e emojis proprios.

Comment: Realmente são essas aspas. Está tudo em UTF-8. Mas vê alguma fora de contornar isso? Pois preciso listar mais de 7000 textos, e muitos estão assim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu já comentei, me parece provável ser alguma conversão das aspas ASCII em algum unicode, talvez o próprio Wordpress esteja convertendo na hora de salvar, tornando em `“` (U+201C) quando a aspas (`"`) forem a esquerda e `”` (U+201D) quando forem a direita de algum texto

Note que apesar de semelhantes aos da tabela ASCII não se tratam do mesmo codepoint. Sua página PHP deve estar em iso-8859-1 ou windows-1252 (ambos assumidos pelo apache ou pelo navegador), ou se seu PHP estiver mesmo em UTF-8 então significa que esses caracteres não são aspas tradicionais, mas sim aspas criadas pela própria turma do WP para usar codepoints e emojis próprios.

Não vou afirmar que esta é a melhor solução, mas como está trabalhando com outro banco e não com a API do Wordpress diretamente (talvez ele próprio forneça algo que "decodifique" o que eles mesmos fizeram) o `iconv` (precisa estar ter libiconv, a maioria dos servidores PHP tem - são "compilados" com isto):

```
<?php

$exemplo = '“Cavalo dado não se olha os dentes”, disse a professora
Segunda linha';

$exemplo  = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $exemplo);

$texto = nl2br($exemplo);

echo $texto;
```

outra solução provisória seria `str_replace` (provavelmente terá que usar `utf8_decode`), assim:

```
<?php

$exemplo = '“Cavalo dado não se olha os dentes”, disse a professora
Segunda linha';

$exemplo  = str_replace(array('“', '”'), '"', $exemplo);

$texto = nl2br($exemplo);

echo $texto;
```

Vale lembrar que o documento PHP que usar isto terá que ser salvo em "Utf-8 sem BOM".

Você também pode começar a usar `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`, mas isso realmente só se desejar e claro que as aspas ali continuarão a ser os UNICODEs `“` (U+201C) e `”` (U+201D)

Comment: Valeu, colocando para repor “ não funciona. Mas acabei descobrindo que os valores das aspas são  e (< 0x94 >e < 0x93 >). Me ajudou muito, obrigado!

Comment: @caiocafardo o iconv funcionou? Copiei da string que colou na sua pergunta, no teste que fiz ele funcionou: https://ideone.com/yO1Wsh, vale notar que tudo isto eu presumi que você esta usando ISO88591 ou windows1252 com codec em sua página.